# Change reference in the table

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a table `A` which has foreign key field to the table `B`. Now i want to change this reference to table `C`. I'm doing following query:

```
ALTER TABLE A ALTER COLUMN key_id TYPE integer REFERENCES C(id);
```

Bug getting error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REFERENCES"
```

How can i do it correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **DROP CONSTRAINT** clause:

```
alter table a drop constraint <constraint_name>;
alter table a add constraint <constraint_name> foreign key (key_id) references c(id);
```